# Type { [x: string]: T[S]; } is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have this code part, that is pretty simple:

```
interface A {
    z: string;
    y: number;
}

let newA = <T, S extends keyof T>(key: S, value: T[S]): Partial<T> => {
    return {[key]: value};
}
```

And I see an error message:
`Type '{ [x: string]: T[S]; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'`

I can suppose that the problem is related to `{}`, that it always maps `key` to be `string`

But even with explicit type says that that should be `string` I have no result

Only one working solution was to just remove `Partial<T>`, but that's not a good one

Hope to get some answer from some expert-level `typescript` guy who can describe the mechanism of that problem and also to get the solution of this situation

**Note!** The problem is related only to generic case. Without that everything goes okay.

[Typescript Playground with this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20QLwC5kBnMKUAcwG4c8BPYkAVwFsAjaWgXyywBsIYZCAgB3dAF5kAHgAqAGmQBlZBAAekEABMSyANYR6AexjI5APgAUhxiqUA3OP2YRicgNrKAugEpiAApwUGDAzvIWyJKR2HjIUELMUCCYHrbexE4uENw8QA)

Comment: how do you call this function?

Comment: There is no call. Error is on type level. Later I suppose it would be something like:
`newA('z', '10')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Partial. Objects with computed keys are always infered to `{[prop:string]:any infered type}`

You can overload your function to avoid such behavior:

```js
type Json =
    | null
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | Array<JSON>
    | {
        [prop: string]: Json
    }

function record<Key extends PropertyKey, Value extends Json>(key: Key, value: Value): Record<Key, Value>
function record<Key extends PropertyKey, Value extends Json>(key: Key, value: Value) {
    return { [key]: value };
}

const result = record('a', 42) // Record<"a", 42>
```